# how to link a menu item to its right section with transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to implement the same principle that my jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/BjpWB/4/ shows into my Wordpress Site.

So my navbar.js is currently like this:

```
(function( $ ){   
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".burguer-nav").on("click", function(){
          $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open");  
       });        
       function scrollToAnchor(aid){
            var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
            $("header nav ul li:first-child a").addClass("about-item");
            $("header nav ul li:last-child a").addClass("contact-item");
        }
        $(".about-item").click(function() {
           scrollToAnchor('about-us');
        });
        $(".contact").click(function() {
           scrollToAnchor('contact');
        });
   });    
})(jQuery);
```

And this is how one of my sections look like:

```
<a name="about-us"></a>    
<section class="about container about-marker">           
    <?php               
    $queryposts = array(                            
        'post__in' => array(7),                 
        'post_type' => 'page',                
        'posts_per_page' => -1,                  
        'order' => 'ASC'             
        );                     
    $lastblog = new WP_Query( $queryposts );                        
    if($lastblog->have_posts() ):                
        while($lastblog->have_posts()): $lastblog->the_post(); ?>                    
            <?php the_content(); ?>                  
                <?php endwhile;            
                endif;                        
                wp_reset_postdata();       
                ?>    
</section>
```

But it seems like my function scrollToAnchor is not taking any action because when I inspect the element I don't see the classes that Iaded to the a tags.
This is the is the site that am working on:http://scentology.burnnotice.co.za/
How can I implement this function correctly so that whenever I click on about or contact it goes to the respective section without having to jump?

Answer (score 1):

Give an ID to your div and you can do that:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

But JQuery animate has bad performance. If you want really smooth animation you can use [velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org) and take an example on this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKLzLQ

Comment: I don't quite follow. The snippet you sent does not work.

Comment: Oops, this codepen works perfeclty on safari but not on chrome. Maybe the library import is bad. But If you look at http://velocityjs.org/#scroll there is a good example for you to scroll easily with velocity.js

Comment: I updated the codepen.io link. It works now you can try again

Comment: But I guess that first problems need to be solved first. If you inspect the element yo will see that the classes I tried to add to the link are not added...meaning that there is problem in the function

Comment: Will try to implement now and let you know if I find any constraint

Comment: @John.Perhaps I must do something different that I dont know as it's WordPress like I mentioned previously. Because when I implement this code and try to click on a menu item,nothing happens.I noticed that it is because of the e.preventDefault();.

Comment: if the preventDefault solution make you happy it's ok

Comment: @John.No,I meant to say that the prevent Default for some reason is the reason why nothing happens when I click on the item.But yet again it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121835/discussion-between-john-and-wosley-alarico).

Answer (score 1):

Please try this javascript snippet.

```html
(function( $ ){   
 $(document).ready(function () {

  $("#primary-menu > li > a").on("click", function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var bookMark = $(this).attr("href").substring(1,$(this).attr("href").length);
   bookMarkTag = $("a[name='"+ bookMark +"']");
   if(bookMark !== undefined) {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: bookMarkTag.offset().top}, Math.floor(bookMarkTag.offset().top));
   }
   
  })
 });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I have edited my answer above, please use above javascript code snippet and check. Thanks!

Comment: It does make a difference,but...It seems like the further down the section is,the faster is scrolls down. Eg:When I click on about item,it goes fine to the about section.When I click on products &services it goes a bit faster.And if I click under contacts,it goes way much faster.
Is there a way to control the speed?

Comment: I have modified the code to make a constant speed, you can actually multiply/divide some number with second parameter in animate function to change the constant speed. Actually the second parameter represents the time by which it will animate to that element, so you have to give variable time based on variable distance. Hope it helps!

Comment: That really maks a great difference. But how I can I take control of the speed? Let's say I want it to be a liittle bit faster.

Comment: As i told you can actually multiple or divide by some number to make faster or slower. change the second parameter like this Math.floor(bookMarkTag.offset().top/5)

Comment: I just doubled checked your answered.
There are just two deficiency that I see so far.First and main is that the navbar goes on top of the section title when it goes to the respective section.I added this on css [name="about-us"] {
    height: 55px !important;
    display: block !important;
} but it shows not to be practical because there will be a big gap on the top very easy to note in case the person scrolls down manualy 
Second is that regardless of the size I add,it always slows down a bit when I try to move from about to contact section.
http://scentology.burnnotice.co.za

Comment: @Wosley Alarico. De-activate your widgetkit slider and see if it will still give the pause when you click on cotact us